# Passing by pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on a C++ program for school with VS13. I need to insert data into a BST. I was given a function defined as Add(int dataValue); (under public) which only takes the data value. I defined a second Add() function that also takes a Node* as a parameter so as to make Add() recursive. (see .h portion of code below)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

class HW2BST
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int Data;
        Node* Left;
        Node* Right;

        Node(int dataValue);
    };

    Node* m_root;

    bool Add(Node* root, int dataValue);

public:
    bool Add(int dataValue);
```

My problem is that when tree.Add(int) is called from main, I try and then pass m_root into the second Add(Node*, int) function to insert the data. Stepping through the function and watching m_root and root as it runs I see that inside of Add(Node*, int) root is set to NULL as I expected. As it steps through root->Data is correctly assigned the dataValue, and root->Left and root->Right are correctly assigned to NULL. But those assignments don't pass back to m_root. Once the function exits, root is destroyed, m_root is not updated and I'm left with no tree. (see .cpp below)

```
#include "HW2BST.h"

using namespace std;

HW2BST::Node::Node(int dataValue)
{
    Data = dataValue;
    Left = Right = NULL;
}

HW2BST::HW2BST(void)
{
    m_root = NULL;
}

bool HW2BST::Add(int dataValue)
{
    return Add(m_root, dataValue);          // Add (overload) recursively searches then inserts dataValue, then returns result
}

bool HW2BST::Add(Node* root, int dataValue)
{
    if (!root)                              // verify if node exists
    {
        root = new Node(dataValue);         // if node does not exist, implement new node and set dataValue
        if (!root)                          // if node not allocated correctly, return false
            return false;
        else                                // else return true (both new node implemented and value added to tree)
            return true;
    }
    else if (dataValue < root->Data)            // if not empty, check data value with current data
        return Add(root->Left, dataValue);      // if less than, travel down left child
    else if (dataValue > root->Data)
        return Add(root->Right, dataValue);     // if greater than, travel down right child
    else
        return false;                           // if equal to, ignore (double entry)
}
```

I have talked to my professor and he said something about using Node** instead, but when I tried that I couldn't get the types to reconcile (i.e. root->Data kept throwing error C2227).

I know the solution is simple, I just can't seem to grasp what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a problematic line:

root = new Node(dataValue);

It's problematic because C++ by default passes arguments by value, and that goes for pointers as well. This means that inside the function `root` is a *copy* of the original pointer, and changing a copy will of course not change the original.

You need to pass the pointer *by reference*:

```
bool Add(Node*& root, int dataValue);
```

---

You can of course *emulate* pass by reference using pointers, like it's done in C, but then you have to remember to dereference the pointer as well as use the address-of operator `&` when passing the pointer. But since C++ have proper references this is not needed.